# How many instances of curl can be opened at the same time

Tags: curl

i have script curl command there are 10000 curl command 
must be run ,i put them in while but my question how much while limit
100 or 1000 what the safe number to run with out load or problem in same second

Comment: I'm not sure there's a general rule - even if there is, it must depend on your system parameters. If you already have the script, why don't you simply try to determine the limit on your system?

Comment: I will do this but what is the acceptable limit so that the connection is not lost when the loop is executed

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to set a number - it really depends on your OS (you may be able to control number of running processes or number of open files), your network, cpu etc.

I strongly suggest you test it on the system that meets your requirement for running your code.

I also recommend you use multi-curl, which is meant for such a job - have a look here for example: [curl_multi_init](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_init.html)

Comment: You did not post any code (or even say what language & OS you use) - so what help do you expect, man? Edit your question and add the code you need help with, say what is not working, and people here will gladly help.

Answer (score 0):

it will mostly be limited by how much RAM you have. also note that the max number of processes allowed on most linux distros by default, is `32768` processes. which can be edited with `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` up to a max of circa 4.2 million million processes (or 2^22 to be exact) - and god knows what the process limit is on Windows, but i assume its significantly lower than Linux's limits.  but do you have terrabytes of ram?

edit: this question is not about programming, i think you should ask at https://serverfault.com or https://superuser.com instead.